# How to recieve silent push notification while app is TERMINATED/KILLED on ios 15

Tags: swift, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have been looking all over the threads of a way to make the app recieve the silent push notification while the app is terminated.

I have tried:

```
{
    "data" : {
        "foo" : boo
    },

    "apns" : {
     "header" :{
      'apns-priority' : '10'  && i also tried 5
              
           }
   
    "aps" : {
        "content-available" : 1
    },
  }
}
```

I know it´s possible since ton of apps use it to update app content while app is killed or after mobile restart. When I open the console I can see that the message is arrived but my app doesnt wake up.
I have made a `print('xx')` right at the beginning of my app.

I have no issue receiving data notifications on background/foreground,